# For loop substitute for Big data

Tags: r, for-loop, time, data.table, time-series

I am having huge data that contains millions of records. I am just sharing subset of it.

```
    data<-structure(list(email_address_hash = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0004eca7b8bed22aaf4b320ad602505fe9fa9d26", 
    "00198ee5364d73796e0e352f1d2576f8e8fa99db", "35c0ef2c2a804b44564fd4278a01ed25afd887f8"
    ), class = "factor"), open_time = structure(c(1L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 
    2L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c(" 04:39:24", " 06:31:24", " 07:05:23", 
    " 09:57:20", " 10:39:43", " 19:00:09", " 21:12:04"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("email_address_hash", 
    "open_time"), row.names = c(NA, -7L),  class = c( 
    "data.frame"))
    require(data.table)
    setDT(data)
```

This is how my data looks like

[image]

I want to put open_times of every email_address_hash in front of it in form of a vector. I tried the below approach

```
data <- data[, .(open_times = paste(open_time, collapse = "")), by = email_address_hash]

str(data)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ email_address_hash: Factor w/ 36231 levels "00012aec4ca3fa6f2f96cf97fc2a3440eacad30e",..: 2 16 7632
 $ open_times        : chr  " 04:39:24 10:39:43" " 21:12:04 07:05:23 06:31:24" " 09:57:20 19:00:09"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

There are two things which I want to resolve

1) First wanted to remove leading whitespace from open_times

2) I wanted to treat every open_times in front of email_address_hash individually . See below the element of open_times was concatenated into a single element.

**Current Output**

```
data$open_times[1]
[1] " 04:39:24 10:39:43"

NROW(data$open_times[1])
[1] 1
```

**Desired Output**

```
data$open_times[1]
[1]"04:39:24" "10:39:43"

NROW(data$open_times[1])
    [1] 2
```

For a single element I can do like

```
unlist(strsplit(trimws(data$open_times[1]),split = " "))
```

But as my data is huge I wanted to avoid for loop as it is taking so much to iterate over all these things.Can anyone provides me a solution that is faster on big data ? Millions or even Billions of records . Solution with data.table is more appreciable

Please let me know if anything is unclear to you.

Comment: Try `data[,list(open_time=list(open_time)),by=email_address_hash]`.

Comment: Interesting. Upvote for well asked question. Big Data frameworks i would only consider if you have a lot of further analysis to do. If it is just the formatting any reason it has to be done in R? If i have computational intensive formatting that i want to do within R I setup an EC2 instance with http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/ (2-3min) and let in run overnight, in your case an R Server could solve that with sapply() till tomorrow morning.

Comment: @nicola This will give me a list and further in order to convert that into vector I required for loop or something else

Comment: @user110244 Keep in mind that `NROW(data$open_times[1])` can't return 2. `NROW(data$open_times[[1]])` could, but just if `data$open_times` is a `list` (as it is in my comment).

Comment: Thank you for notifying the typo  . I have corrected my mistake.

Comment: Are you sure you are understanding my comment? In order to give your desired output, the column must be a `list`. You cannot have your output and the column not being a `list`.

Comment: You are right. Kind of exhausted with my work. Re-edited that. I don't want list in my output. So I guess I was right previously. I can easily get a list by using data <- (as.data.frame(apply(data,2,function(x) trimws(x,which = "left")))). But this is not what I wanted

Comment: Look, the line in the last comment is awful. Just `data[,open_time:=trimws(open_time)]` will trim spaces on the `open_time` column and is much more efficient. Again, your last edit shows an impossibile desired output. `data$open_times[1]` can *never* return a `vector` of two elements. It can return a `list` with a vector of two elements. If you don't get the difference, I suggest you to dedicate some time in studying fundamentals of R.

Answer (score 1):

[Hadoop MapReduce](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_mapreduce.htm) might be what you need here. I've used it before for projects like counting the number of occurrences of phrases in huge collections of text. I imagine it could be repurposed for this too?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Right now I am looking for possible ways to speed up this computation in r

Comment: Not sure if you know, but this sort of answer is often deleted on this site, since it's more of a comment than a complete answer. You don't have enough "rep" to comment right now, but just letting you know.

Answer (score 1):

R is notoriously not good with big data - consider switching to hadoop. With that being said, here's an article on how to make R run faster: https://www.r-bloggers.com/five-ways-to-handle-big-data-in-r/.

As far as getting a column in a vector, I think columns are already vectors:

```
> data[[2]]
[1] "04:39:24" "10:39:43"
> NROW(data$open_time)
[1] 2
```

<sup>*Edit: Thanks to @Frank for pointing out OP was using a data table.*</sup>

Comment: I am not getting it. Are you sure ?

Comment: Ah, thanks @Frank didn't notice that. I'll update my answer.